# How Can I show two tooltips on the same div with Materializecss?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

Hello Guys I have a form en Materialize and I use collapsible component to display it. For each category, I need to display in the accordion (the header of each seccion) two tooltips, the first to show the name of the category and the second to show the text "Active" of an option selected from the form.

I have the next code:

```js
function obtain() {
  var selectCloud_and_or = $("#And_OrCloud").find("option:selected").text();
  $("#cloud_AndOr").text(selectCloud_and_or);
}
$('select').change(obtain);
obtain();
```

```css
.collapsible {
  margin-left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.collapsible').collapsible();
  });
</script>

<!-- select option -->

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').material_select();
  });
  $('select').material_select('destroy');
</script>

<!-- Tooltip -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tooltipped').tooltip({
      delay: 50
    });
  });
</script>

<ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
  <li>
    <a class=" tooltipped" data-position="left" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="First">
      <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="wi wi-cloudy"></i></i><span id="cloud_AndOr"></span><span class="clouds"></span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapsible-body">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 offset-s4">
          <select class="and-or" id="And_OrCloud" name="a_o[]">
                <option value="4" selected="selected">And</option>
                <option value="5">Or</option>
              </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
```

I just want to have two tooltip element, one appears when the user put the mouse throught accordion(the header), in any part of the accordion, and the second needs to appears when the user put the mouse on the option "and/or" that is placed in the accordion (the header). Any idea of how to do that? Right now I just have only one tooltip, but I need two. How can I add the second?

Comment: you can also add an tooltip to the options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to just add the class `"tooltipped"` and `data-tooltip="Message"` to your `collapsible-header`.

**What it does?**

It basically treats your `collapsible-header` as a another *container which needs to be tooltiped* and you can add the desired message in the `data-tooltip`.

```js
function obtain() {
  var selectCloud_and_or = $("#And_OrCloud").find("option:selected").text();
  $("#cloud_AndOr").text(selectCloud_and_or);
}
$('select').change(obtain);
obtain();
```

```css
.collapsible {
  margin-left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.collapsible').collapsible();
  });
</script>

<!-- select option -->

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').material_select();
  });
  $('select').material_select('destroy');
</script>

<!-- Tooltip -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tooltipped').tooltip({
      delay: 50
    });
  });
</script>

<ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion" >
  <li>
    <a class=" tooltipped" data-position="left" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="First">
      <div class="collapsible-header tooltipped" data-tooltip="Another tooltip"><i class="wi wi-cloudy"></i></i><span id="cloud_AndOr"></span><span class="clouds"></span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapsible-body">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 offset-s4">
          <select class="and-or" id="And_OrCloud" name="a_o[]">
                <option value="4" selected="selected">And</option>
                <option value="5">Or</option>
              </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
```